# JSP , javabean and mysql

Tags: jsp, jdbc, javabeans

Hello I am working on a project and any time I try to run I have this error message and I'm still having a problem to figure out about the error. Thanks for any help.

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: The HTTP Monitor server side component intercepted and rethrew an error while processing a JSP or servlet. Please see the stack trace under the root cause message below to identify the problem.

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JavaBeans/Book

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JavaBeans.Book

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've most likely named your classes like the ones in the

> Java EE 6 With Glassfish 3

book. Be careful on how you name your paths. The compiler cannot find the `Book` class.

Comment: i tried to change the name in my code but it still giving me an error .this time with the new name    root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JavaBeans/NewName

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JavaBeans.NewName

Comment: Don't change just the name of the bean, but rather the path in the pom.xml file. You ARE using Maven, right?